# Dynamic model of three dof to state space?

Tags: control, robotics, state-space, robot, dynamic

I´m trying to convert a 3 dof robot manipulator from dynamic model to state space. I saw a video where explains how to convert a 2 dof robot manipulator, but I don´t know how to apply it to a 3 dof robot manipulator...this is the link of the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqNz45I1xtM&list=PLI_ZVs3jy154GEHee2GFAIMBqvr2SnMB4&index=5&ab_channel=ET4860RoboticsandEngineering

I need the equation in matrix form like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, and welcome here! But: Sorry, realistically we're not going to watch an 11 minutes video to really understand what you're trying to do, and what notation your familiar with. Please **edit** your question to include the formulas you mean (you can use `\$x=12\$` for in-line LaTeX formulas, and `$$x=12$$` for equations on isolated lines), and base your question on that :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that your system is of the form
$$ M(q)\ddot{q} + C(q, \dot{q})\cdot \dot{q} + G(q) = J(q)\tau$$
where \$q\$ is the vector of generalized coordinates and \$\tau\$ the vector of forces and torques acting on the system. We start the transformation into a 1rst order system by defining the state vector \$x\$ to be
$$ x^T = \begin{bmatrix}{q^T \ \dot{q}^T} \end{bmatrix}.$$
The first order system is then given by
$$\dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix}{\dot{q} \\ \ddot{q}} \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0_{n\times n} & I_{n\times n} \\ 0_{n\times n} & -M^{-1}(q)C(q, \dot{q})\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} q \\ \dot{q} \end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix} 0_{n\times n} \\ M^{-1}(q)\cdot J(q)\end{bmatrix} \cdot \tau+ 
\begin{bmatrix} 0_{n\times n} \\ -M^{-1}(q)\cdot G(q)\end{bmatrix}$$
by using the rearranged initial equation system
$$ \ddot{q} = M^{-1}(q)\cdot(J(q)\tau - C(q, \dot{q})\cdot \dot{q} - G(q))$$
for expressing the second derivative of the generalized coordinates by the state components and the control inputs. Therefore the system takes the desired form of
$$\dot{x} = A(x)\cdot x + B(x)\cdot \tau + D(x).$$
The approach to finding a 1rst order state space representation of given set of differential equations is always the same. First, define your vector of states. In a second step, express the derivative of the state vector in terms of the states and control inputs by also making use of the original (rearranged) differential equation system.